# Remote hard reboot

Tags: server, remote-control

I am looking for a device that would allow me to remotely hard reboot my computer. The device could use either wired or wireless Internet connection. I just need to be able to remotely ask it to hard reboot the computer (e.g., physically pressing the power button).

Comment: Something like a smart plug type device?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek yes, for example

Comment: In the future you could look out for PCs with the Intel Management Engine which is co-processor on the main board which should be able to do this if being asked from the network. You'd need a vPro enabled CPU though.

Answer (score 2):

The specific model's going to dependent on the style of plug you have locally. Depending on your specific needs, there's two options.

I've not used either of these personally (but I've been looking at them) but if you wanted a prebuilt minimal fuss wireless setup, belkin's WeMo has decent/mixed reviews. Their website is *terrible* but you're looking for something like [this](http://www.belkin.com/us/F7C029/p/P-F7C029/) for your local voltage.

A lower cost option would be a rf controlled plug - [this would be something similar to what I'd look](https://www.amazon.co.uk/LightwaveRF-Wireless-Control-Electrical-Devices/dp/B00ATY2R80) for but once again, your exact options would depend on your local voltages and plugs. Quite a few folks have modded these for rpi control by rewiring the remote.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a raspberry pi or something similar and control a gpio pin of the board remotely. The gpio pin should be attached to an optocoupler ic. With the proper wiring of your button cables to the optocoupler you can hard reset,power on or off the pc.